# Circles at the ends of arrows

Tags: arrows

Consider four kinds of "arrow" symbols: 0. A horizontal line 1. A leftarrow 2. A rightarrow 3. A doublearrow

I'd like to add circles to each end of these arrows, allowing for all possible combinations of "filled" and "unfilled," for a total of sixteen combinations in total. As an example, one may consider the "spoons" offered by the MnSymbol package for reference, as in `\leftspoon` and `\leftfilledspoon`.

Any ideas as to how to achieve this?

EDIT: So to clarify, I want circles on BOTH ends of the arrows. As in O-->O.

Comment: Where is the arrow? Above the filled circle (more or less invisible), outwards or in the inside, ...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use \hbox to create your own arrows by appending other symbols, like this:

```
\def\CircleftarrowCirc{\hbox{$\circ$}\kern-1.5pt\hbox{$\leftarrow$}\kern 1.5pt\hbox{$\circ$}}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. There needs to be a negative on the second kern, but in broad terms this is the answer I was looking for. So the fixed code reads: `\def\CircleftarrowCirc{\hbox{$\circ$}\kern-1.5pt\hbox{$\leftarrow$}\kern-1.5pt\hbox{$\circ$}}`

Comment: @user18921: Good that you spotted the missing negative. I had it in the original code to create the image. It somehow got lost in the copy&paste.

Answer (score 10):

I think the intended arrowtips are the following:

[image: Arrows]

which were produced with the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\def\generateFourVariants#1{% Parameter, arrow style
\xdef\y{0}
\foreach \left in {white, black} {
  \foreach \right in {white,black} {
    \draw[fill=\left]  (0,\y) circle (2pt);    
    \draw[fill=\right] (1,\y) circle (2pt);
    \draw[shorten <=2pt, shorten >=2pt, arrows=#1] (0,\y) -- (1, \y);
    \pgfmathparse{\y+1}
    \global\let\y\pgfmathresult
  }
 }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
  \begin{scope}[xshift=0 cm]
  \generateFourVariants{}
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[xshift=2 cm]
  \generateFourVariants{->}
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[xshift=4 cm]
  \generateFourVariants{<-}
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[xshift=6 cm]
  \generateFourVariants{<->}
  \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But I'm not sure if this answers the OP question...

Comment: Those are indeed the symbols!

Answer (score 7):

Package `txfonts` contains all these symbols, however I am counting nine variants:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{txfonts}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item $-$
\item $\multimapinv$, $\multimapdotinv$
\item $\multimap$, $\multimapdot$
\item $\multimapboth$,
      $\multimapdotbothA$, $\multimapdotbothB$
      $\multimapdotboth$
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: If you look at 4, that's kind of what I'm looking for. Except I'd like the horizontal line connecting the circles to possibly end in an arrowhead.

Comment: @user18921 It's not clear to me. Perhaps you can made some ASCII art or a hand drawing?

Comment: Sure! O---O, O-->O, O<--O, O<->O. That's four of them. Filling in the O's in all combinations gives the remaining twelve.