# Range symbol over character

Tags: symbols

How can I put a range symbol over a character?

The symbol I am looking for is similar to this:

```
\overleftrightarrow{T}
```

But instead of using an arrow at each end, I want to put a black dot at each end.

Comment: Cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85495/15925

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an extensible version.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\range}{\mathpalette{\overarrow@\range@}}
\newcommand{\range@}{%
  \arrowfill@\leftrangebullet\relbar\rightrangebullet
}
\newcommand{\leftrangebullet}{\mathrel{\smallbullet}\joinrel\relbar}
\newcommand{\rightrangebullet}{\relbar\joinrel\mathrel{\smallbullet}}
\newcommand{\smallbullet}{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{$\m@th\scriptscriptstyle\bullet$}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\range{T}+\range{ABCD}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now also `\leftrange` and `\rightrange`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\range}{\mathpalette{\overarrow@\range@}}
\newcommand{\leftrange}{\mathpalette{\overarrow@\leftrange@}}
\newcommand{\rightrange}{\mathpalette{\overarrow@\rightrange@}}
\newcommand{\range@}{%
  \arrowfill@\leftrangebullet\relbar\rightrangebullet
}
\newcommand{\leftrange@}{%
  \arrowfill@\leftrangebullet\relbar\relbar
}
\newcommand{\rightrange@}{%
  \arrowfill@\relbar\relbar\rightrangebullet
}
\newcommand{\leftrangebullet}{\mathrel{\smallbullet}\joinrel\relbar}
\newcommand{\rightrangebullet}{\relbar\joinrel\mathrel{\smallbullet}}
\newcommand{\smallbullet}{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{$\m@th\scriptscriptstyle\bullet$}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\range{T}+\range{ABCD}$

$\leftrange{T}+\leftrange{ABCD}$

$\rightrange{T}+\rightrange{ABCD}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh thanks, in fact, I was having problems with extensions

Comment: Just a quick question, How can I do a half range?. For example for start range: just the left circle and the bar

Comment: @DiegoDiazDominguez Easy enough! `;-)`

Comment: interesting.  the length of the bar isn't the same for a single-ended vs. double-ended extender.  and it's not just the width of the ball on the end.

Comment: @barbarabeeton There is a minimum width, because there is `\relbar` on both sides. This shows for the single symbol.

Comment: but i'm not looking at the one-letter example.  i'm looking at the "ABCD" example.  compare line 1 with line 2.  (the one=letter example is just fine.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton There is just a tiny difference; you can see it better if you only pile the long bits. It's due to the sidebearings of the bullet. As far as I can see it's less than 0.1pt

Comment: apologies.  i was thrown off by the difference in width of the one-letter example.  if i had looked at the relative positions of the plus signs, i would not have been so confused.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fdsymbol}
\begin{document}
$\overset{\leftrightblackspoon}{T}$ or 
$\overset{\leftrightblackspoon}{\text{T}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @DiegoDiazDominguez Glad to hear. Please consider clicking the checkmark symbol left of the answer in order to indicate that this question is answered.

Comment: @marmot Note that `fdsymbol` changes *all* math symbols.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for pointing this out. I am wondering if there is a survey of these issues. To my knowledge, the [calatlogue of symbols](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) does not explain this, or was I looking at the wrong place?

Comment: You should look at the package documentation first: FdSymbol is a font of mathematical symbols designed as a companion to Typotheque’s Fedra family, but it might also fit well to other contemporary typefaces. Note “might”.

Answer (score 2):

How does that look?

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$\overset{\cdot - \cdot}{T}$
\end{document}
```

[image]