# How to write a character overlapping another character

Tags: symbols

How can I write two characters in the same place?

In particular, I want to write an arrow `$\rightarrow$`, and then write a letter such that the arrow strikes through the letter. I found some similar questions ([Range symbol over character](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/404352/range-symbol-over-character), [Substitute a character by another one (Lualatex)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257061/substitute-a-character-by-another-one-lualatex), etc.) but they are not exactly the same question.

Comment: Since an arrow is wider than almost every character, what do you plan to do with the excess?

Comment: A simple but probably naive way is `\rlap{$\rightarrow$}x`. Like egreg wrote, you need to figure out which way the excess should go. Note that the `adjustbox` package give further ways to lap content to all directions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not clear if you want it in text or math...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
In te\stackengine{0pt}{x}{$\rightarrow$}{O}{c}{F}{T}{L}t...

$\ensurestackMath{\stackengine{0pt}{y}{\rightarrow}{O}{c}{F}{T}{L}} = mx + b$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also, it is not clear if you want the arrow's width to be accounted for:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
In te\stackengine{0pt}{x}{$\rightarrow$}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}t...

$\ensurestackMath{\stackengine{0pt}{y}{\rightarrow\!}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}} = mx + b$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Other things that can be easily adjusted above include horizontal alignment (currently centered) as well as vertical height of arrow placement (currently placed at its natural height).

Once the specifics are decided on the use case, this can be easily encapsulated in a macro.

Below, keeping up with the egregs, I implement a macro version (`\overarrow`) for math that preserves the math style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\newcommand\overarrow[1]{\ThisStyle{\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackengine{0pt}{\SavedStyle#1}{\SavedStyle\rightarrow\!}{O}{c}{F}{F}{L}}}}
\begin{document}
$\overarrow{y} = mx_{\overarrow{z}} + b$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

A simple `\makebox[0pt]{..}` can achieve this. Depending on your real use case, this may require a bit of tuning.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}    
\begin{document}

$\makebox[0pt][l]{$\rightarrow$}A$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Here's for text in two versions:

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\asA}[1]{% arrow strike
  \leavevmode\begingroup
  \vphantom{#1}%
  \ooalign{\hidewidth$\mathsurround0pt\rightarrow$\hidewidth\cr#1\cr}%
  \endgroup
}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\asB}[1]{% arrow strike
  \leavevmode\begingroup
  \vphantom{#1}%
  \ooalign{$\mathsurround0pt\rightarrow$\cr\hidewidth#1\hidewidth\cr}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

st\asA{r}uck

st\asB{r}uck

\end{document}
```

[image]

For math:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\as}[1]{% arrow strike
  {\vphantom{#1}\mathpalette\erel@as{#1}}%
}

\newcommand{\erel@as}[2]{%
  \ooalign{\hfil$\m@th#1\rightarrow$\hfil\cr\hfil$\m@th#1#2$\hfil\cr}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a+\as{b}+c_{\as{x}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In case you want a bit of flexibility and the arrow to adjust to the width of the stuff it is running through, you may want to use `tikzmark`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\newcounter{atm}
\newcommand{\arrowthrough}[2][]{\stepcounter{atm}\tikzmarknode[path picture={
\draw[->,#1] (path picture bounding box.west) --
(path picture bounding box.east);}]{atm-\theatm}{#2}}
\begin{document}
 \arrowthrough{x}
 \[ E=\arrowthrough{m}c^2\]
 \arrowthrough[red,-latex]{Hello} \arrowthrough[latex-,thick,blue]{World!}
\end{document}
```

[image]