# Is there a directed angle symbol?

Tags: symbols, angle

Is there a symbol for an angle measured in counter clockwise direction? That would be a directed round arrow for ccw (or cw) direction added to $\angle$.

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Do you have an example picture to show which symbol it is?

Comment: @Marijn  I added a pic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With tikz

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\angle{\tikz[baseline=0mm]{\draw(30:1)--(0,0)--(1,0);\draw[->](-10:0.75)arc(-10:45:.75);}}
\begin{document}
This \angle\ is an angle.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From an idea of @egreg's answer, [How to write a character overlapping another character](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/475653/how-to-write-a-character-overlapping-another-character), with some little adjustments.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathabx}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\roundarrowangle}[1]{% arrow strike
  {\vphantom{#1}\mathpalette\erel@as{#1}}%
}

\newcommand{\erel@as}[2]{%
  \ooalign{\hfil$\m@th#1\angle$\hfil\cr\hfil$\m@th#1#2$\hfil\cr}%
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\rcarrow}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-45}{$\mkern-4mu\scaleobj{.8}{\curvearrowleft}$}}


\begin{document}

$\roundarrowangle{\rcarrow}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Upvoting in progress.... `;^)`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes ahahahahaahahh LOL :-)