# Squigarrows with different heads

Tags: math-mode, arrows

I would like to use the curve line in `$\rightsquigarrow$` changing the pointy arrow for the bullet in `$\multimap$` and `$\multimapdot$` (and also, the inverses of these two, where the dot is at the left side). Is it possible to define symbols like that?

Comment: Welcome! Can you please show a picture of what you want? Is it something [like this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/85495/52406)? (Out of curiosity, what will such a symbol denote?)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? They look really funny ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{txfonts}

\usepackage{trimclip}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\squigmultimap}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \mathpalette\@squigmultimap{}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@squigmultimap}[2]{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{\clipbox{0 {.25\height} {.22\width} {.15\height}}{$#1\rightsquigarrow\m@th$}}}%
  \clipbox{{.55\width} 0 0 0}{$#1\multimap\m@th$}%
}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\squigmultimapdot}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \mathpalette\@squigmultimapdot{}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@squigmultimapdot}[2]{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{\clipbox{0 {.25\height} {.22\width} {.15\height}}{$#1\rightsquigarrow\m@th$}}}%
  \clipbox{{.55\width} 0 0 0}{$#1\multimapdot\m@th$}%
}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\squigmultimapinv}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \mathpalette\@squigmultimapinv{}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@squigmultimapinv}[2]{%
  \clipbox{0 0 {.55\width} 0}{$#1\multimapinv\m@th$}%
  \vcenter{\hbox{\clipbox{{.22\width} {.25\height} 0 {.15\height}}{$#1\leftsquigarrow\m@th$}}}%
}

\DeclareRobustCommand*{\squigmultimapdotinv}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \mathpalette\@squigmultimapdotinv{}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@squigmultimapdotinv}[2]{%
  \clipbox{0 0 {.55\width} 0}{$#1\multimapdotinv\m@th$}%
  \vcenter{\hbox{\clipbox{{.22\width} {.25\height} 0 {.15\height}}{$#1\leftsquigarrow\m@th$}}}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\centering

$A \multimap B$

$A \squigmultimap B$

$C \squigmultimapdotinv D$

\bigskip

$n_{A \squigmultimapdotinv B} + x^{C \squigmultimap D}$

\bigskip

$\frac{A \squigmultimapdot B}{C \squigmultimapinv D}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I needed! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh, it is? I was unsure since there are different styles of squiggly arrows. Some have a less squiggly line. You need to stick with `txfonts` if you want to use these.

Comment: I see. It's true that I was thinking about the less squiggly ones, but in any case these would work. Otherwise I already have the resources.

Comment: @PTV Yes, you can use the above code also to stick together other arrow tails and heads. You only would need to adjust the values in the `\clipbox` then.